# Set icon without *.pro

Tags: visual-studio, qt, icons

I have an application written with Qt (I use VS + Integrator). Need to set an icon for it. I read "Setting the Application Icon" tutorial, but i can't use this method because I have no *.pro file. Googled for an hour and found no solution :( Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an application which is simply an empty [QMainWindow](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qmainwindow.html) (or some other widget) and then create a qmake project for it.  You can typically do this with:

```
qmake -project
```

Then modify the qmake file per the [Setting the Application Icon](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/appicon.html#setting-the-application-icon-on-windows) tutorial and rebuild your `Makefile` by running `qmake`.

Now examine the commands that are being executed and emulate that process on your build system.

[These instructions](http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/FAQ-VISUALSTUDIO-Change-Icon) might work if you're running Visual Studio.

Comment: Finally i made it =) Thanks for answer.